# prerequisites for Auto hosted Apps Office 365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, azure, autohosted

I want to build Apps for SharePoint 2013. The model that makes the most sense for me are Auto hosted apps.

I already have an Office 365 SharePoint online account. But I absolutely have no Idea which Azure account I need. (there are so many options)

So my question is: which azure account do I need to develop auto hosted Apps in Sharepoint online?

regards
Alex

Comment: Can you explain your question some more. Just activate an Azure account on http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/ and make sure you are using your Office 365 admin credentials to create your Azure account.

Comment: Ok, so i need my Office 365 admin credentials to log in to azure. That is the ways these two systems get connected?

Comment: Yes. Use your O365 admin credentials. Posted it as an answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an account in Azure using your Office 365 credentials. When you use these credentials an Azure AD connected to your Office 365 instance will be automatically created.